# Is it possible to charge a mobile phone powerbank using a 12 v motorbike battery and if so how?

Tags: power, battery-charging

I want to find a way to use a 12 volt motorbike battery to charge a mobile phone powerbank. Anyone knows if this is possible and if so how to do it?

Comment: Get a car USB charger, wire a cigarette lighter socket up to the battery, plug charger into cigarette lighter socket, plug powerbank into charger?

Answer (score 2):

The way to achieve what you want is to find a way to convert your 12V bike battery to 5V. The 5V can then be connected to the phone power bank. As you probably already know almost all phone power banks charge from a 5V source.

I see two ways to do this. One is to purchase a automotive phone charger. These are typically designed to plug into a cigarette lighter socket. You can also purchase these sockets and make up a connection to your battery.

Another approach is to check eBay or Amazon and look for a step down voltage converter module. These small circuit board modules are inexpensive and you can find types that will easily convert your 12V to 5V. Many have adjustable outputs. You should easily find modules capable of outputting the 2A or 3A at 5V to charge your power bank.